# Object for generating HTML for hyperlinks

Tags: php, object-oriented, html, url

I have a function that generates HTML for hyperlinks. It's arguments may be string literals or variables read from the database. An example call to this function looks like:

```
hLink('http://example.com', 'website', 'section', 'input=0', '_blank');
```

which returns:

```
'<a HRef="http://example.com?input=0#section" target="_blank">website</a>'
```

The first argument is required, and the remaining four have defaults.

In my first foray into object-oriented programming, I've written a replacement for this function by a method defined in a class, so the function calls are replaced with calls to that method acting on an object from that class. I've written two versions:

- In the first version, each link works by creating a new instance of the class, with the required arguments of `hLink()` handled by the class constructor, and optional arguments handled by setting properties of the object, and then an output method `hLink()` finally acting on those properties to generate the HTML link. If you want to see the code for this version, it's in the edit history of this question, but I've removed it in favor of the second version, which I think is probably better.
- In the second version, the class has no constructor. One instance of the class is created and all links are generated by this one object. The class has a method `clear()` that resets all the properties to empty, as well as additional methods to set the values of any properties that are needed, and finally an output method `hLink()` to generate the HTML link.

I wrote the second version because it seemed that the first was wasteful by creating an object for each link, and those objects were never used again after generating the HTML. So the second version reuses the same object repeatedly for this task.

The code for the second version is as follows: (Pardon my formatting. I know it's unconventional, but I find this easier to read.)

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);
$oLink = new link;
class link
    {private $sURL;
     private $sText;
     private $sAnchor;
     private $sQuery;
     private $sWindow;
     public function clear() 
        {$this->sURL    = ''; 
         $this->sText   = ''; 
         $this->sAnchor = '';
         $this->sQuery  = ''; 
         $this->sWindow = ''; 
         return $this;
         }
     public function URL(string $sURL)       {$this->sURL    = $sURL;    return $this;}
     public function text(string $sText)     {$this->sText   = $sText;   return $this;}
     public function anchor(string $sAnchor) {$this->sAnchor = $sAnchor; return $this;}
     public function query(string $sQuery)   {$this->sQuery  = $sQuery;  return $this;}
     public function window(string $sWindow) {$this->sWindow = $sWindow; return $this;}
     public function hLink()
        {return('<a HRef="' .  $this->sURL . 
                              ($this->sQuery  == '' ? '' : '?' . $this->sQuery) . 
                              ($this->sAnchor == '' ? '' : '#' . $this->sAnchor) .
                        '"' . ($this->sWindow == '' ? '' : ' target="' . $this->sWindow . '"') .
                 '>' . $this->sText . '</a>');
         }
     }
echo('<p>Link to ' . $oLink->clear()->URL('http://example.com')->text('website')->anchor('section')->query('input=0')->window('_blank')->hLink() . ' in text</p>');
```

I've tested the above code as a freestanding script, and it does output the intended:

```
<p>Link to <a HRef="http://example.com?input=0#section" target="_blank">website</a> in text</p>
```

I'd like to know if I'm doing this right, or even if I should be doing this at all (i.e., if this is a sensible use of objects). Is this the best way to generate HTML for hyperlinks embedded in text in PHP?

Comment: Being [discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8943/please-reopen-php-object-for-html-hyperlink)

Comment: What's the use case for the function (or class)? How t's better than just a hyperlink written as is?

Comment: If by "as is", you mean as a string literal, the purpose of the function (and now class) was to allow links to be generated dynamically, mostly from database data. For example, if the URL of a linked reference changes, I change it in the database, and all links automatically update.

Comment: I still don't get it. Don't you store your links as string literals in a database?

Comment: No, the database stores the URLs, not the HTML code. It's not just the URLs that can change, but also the link text (which could be an image tag), querystring, anchors, and window names. Using the function (or method) allows all of that to be determined dynamically.

Comment: I still don't get it. do you store different query parts in the different fields in the database? if so, isn't is an overkill? If you store an entire URL, why can't you just echo this URL from the database straight away? can you show a code that is actually printing a link from database data?

Comment: It seems that you want to debate the usefulness of doing this, whether it's done by a function or a class. That may be a worthwhile debate, but takes us away from the question I asked. Can we just take it as given that doing it is useful to me, and focus on the question of whether it's sensible to do it using objects and whether the class shown is the best design?

Comment: So you don't have a clear idea how it would be used. That's the first question which you should answer for yourself, and other answers would be drawn from this one.

Comment: As a general suggestion, I would separate the URL generation from HTML generation. That's two different matters and a class should cover only one, according to the **Single responsibility principle**.  But again, there should be a clear and consistent use case for both in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I know exactly how it is used. I have hundreds of calls to the function hLink() in my websites, and I'm looking at converting them to using the method $oLink->hLink() instead. If the URL is internal, then generation of the URL is handled separately, as you suggest. My question is specifically about whether it makes sense to use an object to generate the HTML instead of a function and if the class as shown above is the best way to do it. I wish someone would please talk about that!!!

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. After getting an answer you are [not allowed to change your code anymore](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference).

Answer (score 2):

For the suggested use case having an object is an overkill.

As far as I can tell from the code provided, every link is generated only once, which makes class variables; a dedicated method to clean the state; and a code to instantiate an object all unnecessary. So a function would be more appropriate here.

Besides, as it seems that a code is more intended to create an HTML `<a>` tag dynamically than to create an URL, and also in order to follow the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), I would change the list of parameters to just

```
hLink('http://example.com/?input=0#section', 'website', '_blank');
```

which will make parameters more sensible and consistent.

Comment: "every link is generated only once": Not true. Links can appear many times in different pages, and sometimes in different places on a single page. / The "code is more intended to create an HTML <a> tag dynamically than to create an URL": Correcting what I said before, since the query and anchor are part of the URL, this is doing both. The single responsibility here is to generate the HTML tag, and the URL is one of its attributes. It is not suitable to treat the URL as a single parameter because any given webpage may need to be called with different queries and anchors.

Comment: I answered based on the information provided in the question.